# Understanding of routing/mapping URL in Flask

Tags: python, flask, routes

I have been working on this [tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) in order to learn Flask. After accomplishing all steps, I decided to modify some code so as to learn on bugs ;) how everything works. I have the problem with understanding of the process (probably routing) behind this function:

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
     return "Cheers"
```

which I have tried, pasting to search engine:

> http://localhost:5000/index

The result - the message on a screen. Then I have changed the code to:

```
from package import app

@app.route('/wiki')
def got_it():
     return "Now you messed up"
```

and got the error on Wikipedia page. I have typed:

> en.wikpedia.org/wiki/Messed_up

I am very new to Flask, nevertheless I would like to ask you for further information or explanation, why the change of the URL rule didn't work. Is it the matter of encryption of Wikipedia website or does an app need the IP address to work? I have read about routing on several websites, however - supposedly - I didn't notice the explanation.

Quick edit:
- **Wikipedia error**: no such an article on Wikipedia - typical message, when you type wrong address in the template: *en.wikpedia.org/wiki/Article*

- Wikipedia is only an example - the first website which has crossed my mind
- **I wanted to checkwhether all URLs could work for flask app or whether routing is connected to special cases, for example - without *encryption***

Dear All Contributors to the question:

I have tried **marxmacher**'s suggestion:

> http://localhost:5000/wiki

which resulted in the message on a screen. Thus - **it worked**. However, I would like to know, **why did Flask app need *localhost* in this case and didn't work on Wikipedia template (*en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*)?**

Comment: I don't follow any of this question. Why is Wikipedia involved in this?

Comment: "got the error.." what error? what does "didn't work" entail?

Comment: what is the from app import app. that you are importing.

Comment: why is the import changed from the first to second ?

Comment: @fgh does http://localhost:5000/wiki work or not?

Comment: Nothing in the code you've given shows any redirection to a Wikipedia article

Comment: Your edits are making your question more and more unclear.

Comment: Try to be more clear on what you are trying to do. DO you want to redirect people who come to your site?

Comment: Indeed, marxmacher, it worked. Why? Does Flask app need IP?

Comment: If so you can use https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.redirect

Comment: Thank you, marxmacher. I got the impression that you are the least harsh-sounding contributor to the question. ;) I am aware of my lack of knowledge - that's why I ask questions. I have to admit, that I have done some reading about routes, but you have pointed out that it wasn't so relevant to the issue. I understand that Wikipedia may work on different IP address, however I am curious **how** Flask app work and with which url does it *interact* (and why)? Could you recommend some reading?

Comment: Do I have to delete the question with so many downvotes or is there a chance to improve it so as to help others solve their problems?

Comment: you dont need to delete the question. Best start for you would be to read flask documentation and go from there. there are some tutorials on real python also. good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why this worked:

```
http://localhost:5000/wiki
```

Your Flask App is running on your local machine right now. It will not work for en.wikipedia.org/wiki since wikipedia.org is a domain name owned by someone other than you.

If you want your Flask app to be publicly visible you need a public IP and point your Flask app there so people coming to your public IP can be served by your Flask app.

Comment: I'm not sure what issue you're answering to or why this would change anything